# Weblogic Datasoure giving ORA-12519

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I am trying to create new **datasource** in the **Weblogic 12c (version: 12.2.1.3.0).**

Below are the details of the databasource:

1. Name: TestDataSource
2. JNDI Name: jdbc/test.data
3. DatabaseType: Oracle
4. Database Driver: Oracle's Driver (Thin XA) for Instance
   connections; Verions: Any
5. Database Name: XXXX
6. Host Name: xxxxxx
7. Port: 1521
8. Database User Name: XXXX
9. Password: XXXX
10. Driver Class Name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
11. Select Targets: serverName

After saving I am getting below exception:

```
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found 
Substituted for the exception oracle.net.ns.NetException which lacks a String contructor, original message - Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

I am able to connect to the same database via SQLDeveloper without any error.

Please let me know if I am missing any property or step while setup.

Comment: Check with your DBA if the max number of processes of your database has been reached.

Comment: Check that you are actually connecting via a Service Name in SQL Developer or an SID ? Could it be that in SQL developer you are connecting via SID but above you are entering the SID as the Service Name ?

Comment: doing it via SID and in sqldeveloper also I am connecting via SID

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919072/ora-12519-tnsno-appropriate-service-handler-found and refer to the answer in there that mentions about NOT connecting via a SID..